# By appending the image to list`s element others goes down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of blocks, when I append an image to any element of the list others go down

here is HTML:

```
    <ul class="small_slides">

        <li>
            <img src="../images/icons/add_2.png" class="open_popup" status="off">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="../images/icons/add_2.png" class="open_popup">
        </li>
    ...................
    </ul>
```

here is js code:

```
   function some_event() {

     var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("index");
     var small_slides_child = $(".small_slides li:nth-child("+index+")");

     $("#main_slide, .small_slides li:nth-child("+index+")").append("<img src='"+src+"' class='img_slide'>");
     small_slides_child.css({"border":"1px solid #000000", "box-shadow":"0px 0px 0px 2px #696969"});
     small_slides_child.append("<img src='../images/icons/add_2.png' class='add_2'>");

    }
```

and the css code:

```
 .small_slides li {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 125px;
     height: 75px;
     border: 3px dashed #808080;
     background:#F5F5F5;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 40px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

here it is...

[image]

I really can't understand why does it happen, thank you for your help and advices!

Comment: What is the code _meant_ to do?

Comment: If I had to take a guess (as I'm not sure what you WANT the code to do) - I would say it's because you're adding an image without creating a new `li` tag.

Comment: @Andy I need to append the image into the block (it is with grey color) and also append the "plus" icon to the right side

Comment: @entropic I don't need to create new li, I need to append image inside li

Comment: Is there some kind of fiddle you can post so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.small_slides li {
   vertical-align:top;
   .....
}
```